# pgmpy build error Anaconda Windows

Tags: python, conda, pgm, pgmpy

When installing `pgmpy on Anaconda under Windows, using [these](http://pgmpy.org/install.html#getting-the-dependencies) instructions, I get

```
Installing coverage-3.5-script.py script to C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\Scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 28, in <module>
    "coveralls >= 0.4"
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 117, in do_egg_install
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 390, in run
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 620, in easy_install
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 671, in install_item
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 729, in process_distribution
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 639, in easy_install
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 674, in install_item
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 696, in process_distribution
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 572, in install_egg_scripts
  File "C:\Users\idf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.1.1-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1640, in get_metadata
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

C:\Users\idf\Downloads\pgmpy>
```

I might need to do:

```
conda create -n pgmpy-env python=3.4
source activate pgmpy-env
```

But then I get this error:

```
C:\Users\idf>source activate pgmpy-env
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\idf>
```

So it seems these instructions assume Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `source` on Windows. Just type:

```
activate pgmpy-env
```

`source` is only needed on Linux and Mac OS X.